# Unable to inject JS into WKWebView in Swift/Cocoa/NextStep / Push user selection on web page in WKWebView to Swift / Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa, webkit

I'm working with an MacOS app which needs to use the WKUserScript capability to send a message from the webpage back to the MacOS app.  I'm working with the article https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/javascript-manipulation-on-ios-using-webkit-2b1115e7e405 which shows this working in iOS and works just fine.

However I've been struggling for several weeks to try to get it to work in my MacOS.  Here is my example of his code which complies fine and runs but does not successfully print the message found in the handler userContentController()

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()

        // Add script message handlers that, when run, will make the function
        // window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage() available in all frames.

        userContentController.add(self, name: "test")

        // Inject JavaScript into the webpage. You can specify when your script will be injected and for
        // which frames–all frames or the main frame only.
        let scriptSource = "window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage(`Hello, world!`);"
        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: scriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
        userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)

     //   let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
     //   config.userContentController = userContentController
     //   let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

        // Make sure in Info.plist you set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `YES` to load
        // URLs with an HTTP connection. You can run a local server easily with services
        // such as MAMP.

        let htmlStr = "<html><body>Hello world - nojs</body></html>"
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlStr, baseURL: nil)

    }
}

extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    // Capture postMessage() calls inside loaded JavaScript from the webpage. Note that a Boolean
    // will be parsed as a 0 for false and 1 for true in the message's body. See WebKit documentation:
    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessage/1417901-body.
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if let messageBody = message.body as? String {
            print(messageBody)
        }
    }
}
```

Another odd thing is that I do not seem to be able to create a simple WKWebView app that loads a page and displays it.  These are all just simple tests and my main application is able to load/display webpages just fine using AlamoFire/loadHTMLString() to display pages, I just have not been able to inject the JS required.

Everything I've done in the conversion is quite straight forward and required little or no change with the exception of the assignment of the userContentController - so perhaps that's the problem?  This example works just fine in iOS with his original sample as a prototype.  https://github.com/rckim77/WKWebViewDemoApp/blob/master/WKWebViewDemoApp/ViewController.swift

I'm guessing there must be something very simple I'm missing here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as it turns out a major part of the issue was that I needed to set the entitlements for both "App Sandbox" and "com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only" both to "no" in the WebTest.entitlements file.

This was not the case in previous versions of XCode (I'm on V10.1) and the default values basically disabled the WKWebView for what I was trying to do with it (ie, load a simple page either via URL or String)

However, Alex's fix did help once I got that solved... with a couple small tweaks (had to add 'self' to the userContentController.add() function.  Also, I added my JS for it's original purpose which was to "push" to Swift every time the user changed the selection on the page.

Here's my final code:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let javascript = """
            function printStatement() {
                try {
                     var foo = window.getSelection().toString()
                     window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage({'payload': foo})
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log('The native context does yet exist')
                }
            }
            function getSelectionAndSendMessage() {
                try {
                    var currSelection = window.getSelection().toString()
                    window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage({'payload': currSelection})
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log('The native context does yet exist')
                }
            }
            document.onmouseup      = getSelectionAndSendMessage;
            document.onkeyup        = getSelectionAndSendMessage;
            document.oncontextmenu  = getSelectionAndSendMessage;
        """

        let script = WKUserScript(
            source: javascript,
            injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd,
            forMainFrameOnly: true
        )

        webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "callbackHandler")

        webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)

        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let html = """
            <div onClick='javascript:printStatement()'>Print Statement</div>
            This is some sample text to test select with
        """

        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }

}

extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {
            guard let body = message.body as? [String: Any] else {
                print("could not convert message body to dictionary: \(message.body)")
                return
            }

            guard let payload = body["payload"] as? String else {
                print("Could not locate payload param in callback request")
                return
            }

            print(payload)
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks Alex for all your fantastic support!

Answer (score 2):

Heres how I have set my WebView on Mac try something like this

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let javascript = """
           function printStatement() {
                try {               
                     window.webkit.messageHandlers
                     .callbackHandler.postMessage({'payload': 'Hello World!'})
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log('The native context does yet exist')
                }
           }
        """

        let script = WKUserScript(
            source: javascript,
            injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd,
            forMainFrameOnly: true
        )

        webView.configuration.userContentController.add(
            name: "callbackHandler"
        )
        webView.configuration.userContentController
            .addUserScript(script)

        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let html = """
            <div onClick='javascript:printStatement()'>Print Statement</div>
        """

        webView.loadHTMLString(html, nil)
    }

}

extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        if(message.name == "callbackHandler") {
            guard let body = message.body as? [String: Any] else {
                print("could not convert message body to dictionary: \(message.body)")
                return
            }

            guard let payload = body["payload"] as? String else {
                print("Could not locate payload param in callback request")
                return
            }

            print(payload)
        }
    }

}
```

Hopefully this answered your question and works if not let me know and i'll try figure it out!

Comment: Thanks Alex for the very fast response, unfortunately I'm still not seeing any results.  I forgot to mention that I'm working in Swift 4, so had to make a couple adjustments to your code to get it to compile.  

But I'm also noticing that you are using a "MessageWebView" rather than a WKWebVew.  Is that a custom class?  I'm not finding anything on it on the web?  So perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Hey oh sorry I thought you were in Swift 4, MessageWebView was a mistake on my part when typing it into stackoverflow. I have the normal WKWebView. Let me know is your html button displaying?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm seeing nothing in the HTML window, not even the HTML page.  I changed the MessageView to a regular WKWebView and it gives a compilation error on webView.configuration.userContentController.add(
            name: "callbackHandler"
        ) (no such function).  I'm guessing it's a function in your subclass?  I tried hard-coding the page to fire the signal on load (w/out the button) and still don't get a message coming through

Comment: I've been hacking around with this for a few weeks now and am clueless why I can't even seem to get a WebView to display HTML w/out using AlamoFire to load pages.  But have been very busy with some other more deadline-based projects so haven't been able to take a more methodical approach

Comment: Hey Alex, it's been a week or so and just checking if you got my response?  It seems that perhaps part of your solution was not included?

Comment: Hey sorry, Jc only just saw this. Sorry I couldn't help anymore I have been extremely bus!

Comment: No worries at all dude... I saw you updated your code.  That was all I needed to get it up an running. Mucho thanks!